# Hover text is broken if text has special symbols when description is given

Tags: html, css

Example:

```html
<a title="A web design community.'test'~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=\|][{};:,<.>?/ **"new test"** " href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a>
```

In tooltip, after the double quotes "new test" is not working.

Is there any possible to show the content in tooltip like this
ex:  testing 'welcome', @ 3 $ ^ & * "flow"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your double quotes in the title close your title automatically. Escape them by replacing `"` with `&quot;` and also [funkwurm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684660/funkwurm) recommends to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively to avoid errors in xml:

```html
<a title="A web design community.'test'~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=\|][{};:,&lt;.&gt;?/ **&quot;new test&quot;** " href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a>
```

Comment: I would replace `<` and `>` as well, `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Comment: In html they do, it's xml that would raise an error. It comes down to personal preference I suppose, but I like to be more "neat", if you will, and use entities in these cases. (come to think of it I would also use `&amp;` in stead of `&`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this is also.

```html
<a title="Answer to your's question.'Test It' :):)'B Happy' :):)&#34;new test&#34;**" href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a>
```